# Django recursive menu

Tags: django, recursion

I'm unable to show the third level on view page

Model

```
class ShopCategory(models.Model):
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
```

View

```
def home(request):
    categories = ShopCategory.objects.filter(enabled=True, language='en', parent__isnull=True)
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'categories': categories}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
<li>
    <a href="/cat/{{ category.url }}/">{{ category.title }}</a>
    <ul>
        {% for child in category.children.all %}
        <li><a href="/cat/{{ category.url }}/{{ child.url }}/">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}

        <ul>
            {% for subchild in chil.children.all %}
            <li><a href="/cat/{{ chil.url }}/{{ subchild.url }}/">{{ subchild.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is what I get:

```
- Beauty
-- Face
-- Make up
```

What I want is:

```
- Beauty
-- Face
-- Make up
--- Lipstick
```

But it doesn't show **Lipstick**. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors. Firstly you should be iterating through `child.children.all`, not `chil...`, and secondly that final loop needs to be moved inside the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest solution in my opinion:

First of all, create some 'recursive_menu.html' template and put this code:

```
<li>{{ category.title }}
        <ul>
            {% if category.children %}
                {% for child in category.children.all %}
                    {%with category=child template_name="shop/recursive_menu.html" %}
                       {%include template_name%}
                    {%endwith%}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </li>
```

As the same time your base template looks like:

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
     {% include "shop/recursive_menu.html" %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Explanation:

1. Code iterates through all of the category items in root 'categories'.
2. Outputs each category and associated layout.
3. If the category has children:

   - Set the category variable as the children of the current categories.
   - Recursive call to current template file.
   - Output any nested children in a nested list.
   - Repeat recursion as necessary.

Result looks like this:

[image]